# Injecting resources into the manifest of a .NET assembly post-build

Tags: .net

Is there a way for me to insert a resource into the manifest of another assembly?

I've been experimenting with MSBuild and ILMerge but apparently a resouce assembly created by the Assembly Linker can not be merged wtih ILMerge, looks like ILMerge cant do a resource only merge.

```
al /out:Resources.dll /embed:Test.txt,Resources.Test
```

ilmerge just yields an error

```
ILMerge.Merge: Could not load assembly from the location 'Resources.dll'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I actually had the answer, my ILMerge version must have been buggy...

I took the C# class template .cs file and compiled that in the simplest way

```
> csc /target:library Class1.cs
```

I then use the Assembly Linker part of the Windows SDK to create a trivial resource assembly (quicker)

```
> al /out:TextFile1.dll /embed:TextFile1.txt
```

This last part failed with a stupid null reference exception, last time I tried this. But just now it worked like a charm.

```
> ilmerge /out:Merged.dll Class1.dll TextFile1.dll
```

You can verify the result using `ildasm`

```
> ildasm /text Merged.dll
...
.mresource public TextFile1.txt
{
  // Offset: 0x00000000 Length: 0x00000003
}
```

...and that's it!

I use this to inject stuff into assemblies post-build as part of the build process. e.g. SVN log information. So that I can track a binary to a specific revision and person.